# please help me to create grid by passing parameters to request action

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

i am applying struts2 jquery grid.the data in the grid will be generated based on the filter selected values and the jsp will be executed where i have written this code.the data type i am using is json and the action is execution here   but i want to pass parameters for this action how can i acheive this without including url in same page.even i tried with type="chain",redirect but i am not getting any grid just json data is displaying

```
    *<s:url id="remoteurl" action="gridaction"/>
    <s:url id="editurl" action="editaction"/>
    <s:url id="selecturl" action="selectaction"/>*

    <sjg:grid id="sjgrid" **dataType="json"** href="%{remoteurl}" caption="Grid Model"
              gridModel="gridModel" editurl="%{editurl}"


               navigator="true"
             navigatorSearch="true"
    navigatorSearchOptions="{multipleSearch:true}"
    navigatorExtraButtons="{
        seperator: { 
            title : 'seperator'  
        }, 
        hide : { 
            title : 'Show/Hide', 
            icon: 'ui-icon-wrench', 
            topic: 'showcolumns'
        },
        alert : { 
            title : 'Alert', 
            onclick: function(){ alert('Grid Button clicked!') }
        }
    }"
          loadonce="true"
            pager="true"
            pagerPosition="center"
            rowList="5,10,20"
            shrinkToFit="true"
            altRows="true"
            autowidth="true"
```

filter="true"

```
      >



        <sjg:gridColumn name="iduser" title="iduser" key="true" hidden="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="uname" title="Username" editable="true" align="center"
                        editrules="{required:true}"
                        />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="passwd" title="Password" editable="true" align="center"
                        editrules="{required:true}"
                        />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" title="Country" editable="true" align="center"
                        edittype="select"
                        editoptions="{dataUrl:'%{selecturl}'}"
                        />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="contact" title="Contact No" editable="true" align="center"
                        editrules="{required:true,number:true,integer:true}"

                        />
    </sjg:grid>
```

Comment: can i used datatype as html or jsp without json is it compulsion to use data type as json

Answer (score 0):

you have to use formIds attribute:

first create a form with the variables you want to send
second reference this form from sjg:grid with the formIds attribute

in the json action you will have all form variables available